# rails 3.1, why I can't override 'create' at Devise::SessionsController?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have devise 1.4.8, and I am trying to override `create` at `Devise::SessionsController` to execute some logic once user signed in.

Here is my class: (stored at \app\controllers\students\sessions_controller.rb)

```
class Students::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   def create
     super
   end
end
```

here is my routes.rb

```
devise_for :students, :controllers => { :sessions => "students/sessions" }
```

but, overridden `create` is never called! instead, only the `create` at super class is called

any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem in the routes.rb,

I have this line, and it worked:

```
devise_for :students do post '/students/sign_in' => 'students/sessions#create' end
```

but, I've deleted all lines for :students at routes.rb

Comment: This still leaves open question for me.